# Why it is so wrong to add also beneficial non Islamic teachings?

Tags: discussion, support

Yesterday, a user asked: **"when it is permissible to abandon another Muslims?"**. I granted him answers, but in the same time I have also added some beneficial non Islamic teachings and also Islamic teachings.

Ok, the problem in here it is: someone complained to me that the: **"the vast majority of this answer has nothing to do whatsoever in the topic of Islam..."**. When I heard this, I got really pissed and I mean it, because that would be a waste of effort.

Why it is so wrong to add also beneficial non Islamic teachings? I thought that every beneficial knowledge from different sides are welcomed...

Answer (score 1):

It may have been helpful but not from an Islamic point of view which is what the questioner may want to know, the community also and what the whole website revolves around. If you want to add some comments make them basic but try not to make majority of your answer from a non-Islamic p.o.v.

Comment: I thought that one can learn anything from anyone as long as this information is good